# Physical simulation in python

Tags: simulations, computational-physics

Is there a "standard" python package used to aid in physical simulations? What is the most popular?

edit: perhaps I should have worded this question differently. Something more to the effect:

Could someone provide an introduction to the common python related tools used in visualizing, stochastically, various motions that one might find in a mechanics course?

Comment: What kind of physics are you trying to simulate? Python comes with (almost) all the mathematical tools you will need to simulate physics from simple Newtonian mechanics all the way to quantum field theory... but using these tools requires an understanding of the theory. One can't make a universal physical simulation package in any language, nature is far too complex for that. There are excellent tutorials for computational physics in Python, though. Did you look at something like http://phys.csuchico.edu/ayars/312/Handouts/comp-phys-python.pdf?

Comment: There's way too many options to make this answerable depending on what kind of problem and how much you want to write on your own vs. use somebody elses code.

Comment: Python is more used as a scripting language than a proper simulation language

Comment: I'm interested in simulating interacting objects, each with individual processes that depend on properties in a shared environment, and a common time. PyGame seems interesting, and there are smaller packages that I have little information on, such as SimPy. Which standard library packages should I keep an eye out for? Thank you for your time! I'm currently in a computational physics course, and it has been very enlightening.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to use the multithreading and multiprocessing facilities of any language for your intended purposes. That's not what they are designed for and the performance will be awful (let alone the heartbreak that you are in for with the debugging!). What you are looking for is called "discrete event simulation", but Simpy's approach is horrible. To make that work beyond toy models, you need to get your hands on a C or Fortran based discrete event simulation kernel, and even then you will be up against some serious limitations if you don't specialize that code.

Comment: I did an entire FEM class using SciPy and NumPy. But it was horrendously slow compared to using Fortran or C (I did all 3 for fun once...). I would recommend Python if you want to focus on algorithm development/understanding how things work but if you actually need to do something more than small problems, skip it and use something else.

Comment: @tpg2114: for suitably large matrix calculations NumPy should be able to catch up with C (but maybe not quite with Fortran implementations). How bad was the difference? Looking at publicly available benchmarks even the NumPy matrix operations come within a factor of five, which is slower than I expected. For large matrices they should almost catch up. Do you know what gives?

Comment: @CuriousOne Not all implementations link against BLAS/LAPACK so they may not be using underlying-Fortran routines found in those libraries. I want to say that under certain matrix sizes, it always does those "in NumPy", ie. in Python, but for larger sizes, if the implementation was linked against BLAS/LAPACK, it will farm it out to those libraries. So I think it all depends on whose installation you use and on what systems.

Comment: @CuriousOne FWIW, we've found the same kind of issue with BLAS and Fortran (using the built-in functions and writing our own): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924573/are-blas-level-1-procedures-still-relevant-for-modern-fortran-compilers/12924660#12924660

Comment: @tpg2114: That's very interesting. I wasn't aware of that problem. Thanks for the input, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: This is an *extremely* broad question, even after "narrowing" it to "simulating interacting objects" (what type of objects, how are they interacting, what scales are involved, etc). It's also fairly opinion-based.

Comment: Just, for what it's worth: the point of python is to script things at the high level, but python is specifically designed to be able to call compiled functions. You can and should write simulation code in a compiled language but definitely consider using python as your "glue" where you might otherwise use shell scripting or whatever. You can also use python to invoke shell commands like running other programs etc. so you can more or less use python as a drop in replacement for the shell... and python is way better.

Comment: As to the new update, I cannot stress how [*vague*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vague) "physical simulations" actually is. Please **explicitly define** what simulations you are referring to, otherwise this constitutes "unclear what you're asking" as well as the other two close reasons I previously mentioned.

Comment: @KyleKanos Apologies for being vague, I think I'm oblivious to how many fields are out there. I've updated my question again.

Comment: @user3465201 - That's still very vague. What level mechanics class -- introductory, upper level undergraduate, or the graduate level? Presumably it's not the introductory level class; those problems are designed to be solved by hand. That means your question encompasses everything from finite element analysis to a model of a supernova to N-body simulations, both large and small, both colliding and non-colliding, plus a whole lot more.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [Computational Science SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com), but you should make it a lot clearer what your needs are for them to have enough information to help you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computational science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of the comments are valuable.

I think that a consensus is building (probably better:  has been built) that the standard base system for science use is the numpy/scipy/matplotlib stack.   But there are packages that don't build on that stack.  I'm afraid you'll have to do some digging to see which packages will work for you.

There are many many many packages that build on the numpy/scipy/matplotlib stack.   There are also many packages for more specialized tasks, such as dealing with large data sets, or inhomogeneous data sets.  And packages for specific scientific fields, astronomy for example.

So you see it's hard to give a straightforward answer.

But one very important package that is extremely useful for adding visualization to a simulation is [VPython](http://vpython.org/)  ("3D Programming for Ordinary Mortals").  I would strongly encourage you to take a serious look at it.

There are also several "batteries included" meta-packages that greatly simplify the installation of python for scientists.   One is [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads), another is [PythonXY](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/), another is [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/).  And, again, there are others.

I think you will have to take a look at what's out there, choose things that looks sensible to you, and start working with them.  My apologies to the many many packages that I haven't mentioned.

Comment: I just visualize using [MayaVi](http://mayavi.sourceforge.net/) or [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org) if I need something more complicated than MatplotLib. Those are really easy to use if you are already using VTK to store data, but it's pretty easy to use regular NumPy with it too.